# Declaring field to use Unicode UTF-16

Tags: teradata

I am trying to use the Unicode UTF-16 character set, but I am unsure how to do this, by default when I use the Unicode character set it uses UTF-8 which changes foreign Spanish, Arabic, etc. characters into ?.  I am currently using Teradata 14.

Comment: I thought unicode data in TD was always UTF-16.  How are you loading your data?

Comment: could you please provide the ddl statement once @BobDunakey

Comment: The issue ended up being with the loader I was using. It was converting the data to ASCII.